# dynamic adding of event targets javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code snippet like this.

```
$(document).on("click", event_target, some_function);
```

**DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR**:

If i pass event_target as null or empty string, all clicks on the document are handled.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

I want that if event_target is an empty string the event shouldn't be handled.

**CURRENT APPROACH**

Now i just add a if statement in the handler and if target is document i simply do nothing.

**Is there a better approach to avoid unnecessarily calling the handler for all clicks?**

Comment: I don't think so... what is wrong with your current approach

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well i thought i wanted to avoid the overhead of calling the handler everytime i click or tap somtehing in the entire document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do what you're currently doing inside an if block? Set up the click handler only if event_target is not an empty string.

```
if (event_target !== '')
    $(document).on("click", event_target, some_function);
```